# hover effect on child div creating focus event on parent div

Tags: html, css

Consider the below code snippet:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
       <label>OPTIONS</label>   
       <div class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
         <label for="checkbox2">Email</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I hover over the `<div class="checkbox">`, focus event of `<div class="form-group form-group-default">` gets triggered; where as in css code I didnt find any relevant hover code for `<div class="checkbox">`.

Comment: You should provide more information, your question is not clear.  I don't know what you mean when you say focus event gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know all events of DOM will get propagate through it's parents. Unless some event handler stops it.

Look at this example.

```
<!-- https://jsfiddle.net/z0ncxhfq/ --> 
<div class="parent">
  <a class="dontpropagate child" href="#one">Link one</a>
</div>
<div id="dont" class="parent">
  <a class="child" href="#two">Link two</a>
</div>
<script>
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".dontpropagate");
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", stopPropagation, false);
}
function stopPropagation(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you have to simply remove the **form-group** styling.

Try:

```
.form-group:focus,
.form-group:hover,
.form-group:active {
    outline: none !important;
}
```